# When is $X$ homotopy equivalent to $X\times X$?

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

When is a topological space $X$ homotopy equivalent to $X\times X$ (with the product topology)?

Clearly if $X$ is contractible this holds, since the product of contractible spaces is contractible. For example, if $X=\mathbb R$ then $X\times X = \mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R \simeq \mathbb R^2$.

When $X$ is not contractible, there are obvious counterexamples: Let $X=S^1$, then $X\times X = S^1 \times S^1 \cong T^2$, and obviously $S^1 \not\simeq T^2$.

What are the necessary and sufficient conditions on $X$ for $X \simeq X\times X$ to hold?

Comment: Another source of examples: find a group $G$ such that $G\cong G\times G$ and let $X=K(G,1)$. (See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43805/when-is-g-isomorphic-to-g-times-g to see that you can even find finitely generated groups with this property.)

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Oh wow, that is super interesting. Is this an open problem in general? I tried searching for it, but didn't find much, so that usually means it's either trivial or very complicated :)

Comment: My guess is that necessary and sufficient conditions are going to be hard to find. Although, if you restrict to spaces that have the homotopy type of CW complexes, you might be able to make some headway on a classification.